# Which HTML5 Canvas library should I use for this purpose?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs, paperjs, scenegraph

I am a newbie on HTML5 and Javascript, but I need to do a visualisation using them.

Here is my domain / problem:

1. I need to visualise a large set of graph nodes, visually a node can be a cycle with colors and transparence.
2. There are two relationships: *include* and *interact*.
3. `include` means one node include other different types of node, visually, users can see a big node with smaller nodes inside itself.
4. `interact` simply means a line connect different nodes. The line should have arrow, label (text), and thickness.
5. For effects, I need animations, such as nodes are not static, but some of them should have the animation of **floating** around (small amount of regular floating movement around a center place); or some nodes should have the **pulse** effect like breathing.
6. User can drag some nodes, if dragging a node, all connected nodes / graph should move accordingly as they are connected.
7. Auto detecting collision should in place. Also, if a collision occurs, all nodes should follow some algorithms to distribute away nicely.

---

Here are my **questions**:

1. Which Canvas library should I use? Since I am a newbie anyway, a nice simple one which fits my needs is the best.
2. What algorithm should I seek for to do the floating and pulse (breathing) animations?
3. What algorithm should I use for dragging a node and all connected nodes follow like a snake?
4. What algorithm should I use for collision and distributing?

Thanks

Comment: Bo you're not new to SO. Just to remember you that questions like "Suggest me a Library" are getting closed.

Comment: [d3js.org](http://d3js.org/)

Comment: @gongzhitaao it is for visualisation?

Comment: Absolutely!  And see [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) and [that](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).  And you could find [more demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock).

Comment: @gongzhitaao damn, your comment almost answer my questions. Can you suggest some algorithms for floatting, pulse, breath, collisions?

Comment: So far as I know, all you want is implemented in d3js.  If you don't want to write those yourself, you may want to dive into the d3js docs like [transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions) and etc.

Comment: floating, pulsing, breathing and etc are some form of [easing effects](http://gizma.com/easing/#cub2).  This could be found in d3js transition.  Collision demo in d3js is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298).  Good luck.

Comment: @gongzhitaao please write all your comments as answer and I will mark yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[d3js](http://d3js.org)**

See elastic node demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), collision demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298).  This page contains tons of [d3js demos](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock)

For [easing effects](http://gizma.com/easing/), you could look into [d3 transition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions).

Good luck!